# Oh-My-Zsh on WSL Showing Question Mark in Command Prompt

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

Edit: I ended up abandoning the default WSL Ubuntu console and moving to Windows Terminal by following the instructions [here](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2020/02/17/setting-up-wsl2-windows-terminal-and-oh-my-zsh/), and now everything is working.

I installed Oh-my-zsh on WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04 if it matters), and I get question marks instead of whatever should be in the prompt. It looks like this (theme is set to "agnoster"):
[Question marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHO1m.png)

I looked it up and the most prevalent advice was to install powerline fonts, so I followed the instructions here: [How to install Powerline fonts on WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148517/how-to-install-powerline-fonts-on-wsl). I indeed was able to set the font to a powerline font in the settings of the console, but the problem wasn't solved (I tried to restart my computer and it still didn't work).

I saw similar questions about iTerm but I couldn't extract from there relevant steps that I can take.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? This is a tutorial by Microsoft on how to install power line fonts on the Command Prompt.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup

Comment: Well, this link made me realize it might be easier to work with Windows Terminal instead of the default WSL Ubuntu console. So I followed the instructions on [this](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2020/02/17/setting-up-wsl2-windows-terminal-and-oh-my-zsh/) link and now everything is working :)

Answer (score 10):

From [this](https://github.com/WhitewaterFoundry/Pengwin/issues/162#issuecomment-656998683) comment:

Right click on the title bar

1. Select Properties
2. Go to the tab Font
3. Select "Dejavu Sans Mono" in the Font section (or "NsimSun")
4. Click the OK

Comment: And if "Dejavu Sans Mono" font is on the list, download and install it from [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans-mono).

Comment: @DanielHjertholm where do I move the zip for the font to appear as an option in the settings?

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Putting the font in C:/Windows/Font worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I shared my solution for oh-my-bash on their issues page: https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash/issues/66

A possible solution for those running on WSL is to make sure the files have correct unix line endings. This command fixed my oh-my-bash install

```
dos2unix ~/.oh-my-bash/**/*
```